# Is it bad not to dispose ISession

Tags: nhibernate

I have NHibernate hooked up in my asp.net mvc application

The ISession is injected into the repository. 
I can not use the session per request pattern because i need a session per conversation aproach.

The NHibernate ISession is used across multiple http requests. The object graph is big and i don't want to load the entire graph in every request. That's why the ISession is stored in the users HttpSession.

The lifecycle of the ISession is configured with StructureMap:

```
For<ISession>().LifecycleIs(new HttpSessionLifecycle()).Use(x =>
{
    var sessionSource = x.GetInstance<ISessionSource>();
    return sessionSource.CreateSession();
});
```

At the end of the conversation i call

```
Session.Clear()
```

to clear the ISession.

When the user creates a new conversation, StructureMap creates a new ISession.
I did not found a way of disposing the ISession.

So is it bad not to dispose it?
Is this holding connections to the database?

Comment: If it doesn't implement IDisposable then... well then there is no Dispose() and Disposing of it makes no sense.  What do the docs say?

Comment: ISession is disposable and as a best practice should be disposed. But the ISession in my application must span across multiple page requests

Comment: When you say you cannot use a session per request pattern because you need a session per conversation pattern, do you mean that you want to hold the session across multiple http requests for the same user?  If you could explain your use case more, it would be helpful to understand your issue.  Thanks.

Comment: Is it an option to detach `the object graph` and save it in your web session?

Comment: The object graph is actualy saved in the web session, but not detached. I do not have experience detaching / attaching with nhibernate, but have read that it should be omitted if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general NHibernate won't keep open connection to DB longer then it needs to. It uses SQL Server connection pool to get connections quickly and return them. So in terms of open connection its not a problem not to dispose a session.

But session also keeps track of all changes in entities and flushes them in DB on dispose/commit transaction, just keep in mind that this feature is there and might chase you

Answer (score 2):

Also be aware about following issue:

https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3046

In some scenarios (if you don't use transactions or if you often perform rollback of transactions) long-living sessions can "eat" a lot of memory. But all allocated memory will be released when session is disposed and collected by GC.